# Renaming a Character in Final Fantasy VII (PC Version)

Tags: final-fantasy-7

Is it possible to rename a character (via some kind of a hack) after he/she joins your team in Final Fantasy VII? I'm playing the re-released (2012) version for the PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Black Chocobo](http://www.blackchocobo.com/) is a save editor for FFVII that can allow you to edit you save file to modify things, like characters, quests, and save location. It should work with all of the PC and console versions.